# What does <A-1> and <Cmd> mean in VIM?

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to switch to vim and I'm having some difficulty trying to understand what these remaps mean.

I'm using this tab plugin from https://github.com/romgrk/barbar.nvim.

In the read me file they have something to bounce from tabs with the commands as the following:

```
nnoremap <silent>    <A-1> <Cmd>BufferGoto 1<CR>
nnoremap <silent>    <A-2> <Cmd>BufferGoto 2<CR>
```

Can anyone enlighten me and future viewers of this thread, what these commands are and what they mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various `*map` commands cause one set of keys to be replaced by another.

`<A-1>` and `<A-2` are special key names representing Alt-1 and Alt-2, respectively (hold down the Alt key, then press 1 or 2).

`<Cmd>` indicates that the following text should not be used literally, but is a command that should be executed instead.

So pressing Alt+1 switches to buffer 1, and pressing Alt+2 switches to buffer 2.

Comment: There is no `remap` command. Also, you should mention `:help key-notation` and `:help 05.4`.

Comment: I should have said `*map`. (I was thinking of the various `*noremap` commands as being a `remap` family prefixed with various mode selectors.)

Comment: Yeah, that "remap" confusion is sadly common.

Comment: What would be option key instead of Alt for mac? @chepner

Comment: Good question. My first guess would be the escape key (since `<A-...>` is a synonym for `<M-...>`--the meta key--, and the escape key usually works as the meta key in most terminals by default. Escape has, of course, the common function of returning to normal mode in `vim`, so I'm not sure what the typical workaround is.